# Typing characters in Swift 4 NSTextFields is causing beeping to occur Mac OS X

Tags: swift, macos

I am new to Swift 4 development and I have what seems like a really basic problem (yet I can’t figure it out) with typing into  NSTextFields
within my application.  The application is structured with  a main View controller that has a view with several NSTextFields for user input.

```
import Cocoa
import CoreWLAN

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSComboBoxDataSource, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate,  NSComboBoxDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var txtTotalCashAmt: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtTotalCheckAmt: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtSubTotalAmt: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtTotalLessCashAmt: NSTextField!
```

The viewDidload function in the main view controller is monitoring for keydown events:

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [NSEvent.EventTypeMask.keyDown]) {
            self.keyDown(with: $0)
            return $0
        } . . . .
```

And there is an override in this main controller for the keydown events

```
  override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent)
    {
       if (event.keyCode == 48 || event.keyCode == 36){
            if(cmboPayer.stringValue.count > 0) {
                if(isOnCmboPayer == true) {. . . . .
```

This all works fine.  Where my problem comes in is that I have 2 segues that can be launched from this main view controller as well with notifications
Set to return to this main view when entry is complete:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(shouldReloadDeposit), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newDataNotifDeposit"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setUserLabels), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newNotifUserDef"), object: nil)
```

These are linked to other controllers with views, and they also except similar NSTextField input, but there is no override on the keyDown on either of the other 2.

```
class UserDefinedCController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate{ }
class AccountMaintController: NSViewController, NSComboBoxDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NSComboBoxDelegate{ }
```

I check the keystrokes on these two using controlTextDidChange to make sure text is entered correctly which also works fine:

```
override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let textField = notification.object as? NSTextField {

            let numChars = textField.stringValue.count
            switch textField.tag {
            case 1000:
                let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789acd@").inverted
                let compSepByCharInSet = textField.stringValue.components(separatedBy: aSet)
                let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
       . . . 
        txtMicrRoutingNo.stringValue = textField.stringValue
```

And I subclassed all the views:

```
import Cocoa

  class View: NSView {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

   }
```

Problem: Every time I type a character on any of the views (the main or the other 2 called via Segue) I get a beep  which is really annoying.
What I have noticed trying to debug is that each time I load the app up and go to one of the views via segue, and type a character in a NSTextField, the 
keydown event on the main view controller executes  (basically it looks the event is firing twice, once on the main view and then on the view that is actually receiving the input).
Any assistance on what I am doing wrong or missing  to prevent the beeps would really be appreciated.

Comment: `keydown` is fired by `self.keyDown(with: $0)`. Please tell us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: How do I stop the beeping after every stroke of the keyboard.

Comment: Why do you call `self.keyDown(with: $0)`?